# How to create a datetime in apex given a datetime string?

Tags: date, datetime, salesforce, apex

With apex, I pass a string like:

```
2017-02-05T01:44:00.000Z
```

to an apex function from javascript, however, when attempting to turn it into a datetime, it gives me invalid date/time error. I can create a date with it like

```
date newdate = date.valueOf(dateString);
```

but if I do `datetime newdate = datetime.valueOf(dateString)` I get the error. I don't get why it sees the string as incorrectly formatted to give invalid date/time. When I create just a date instead of datetime, I lose the time and it sets it to 00:00:00.

Thank you to anyone with some insight on how to create the datetime in apex! I have been trying to find the apex format and from what I see. I can't understand why it thinks this is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
String inpputString = '2017-02-05T01:44:00.000Z';
DateTime resultDateTime = DateTime.ValueofGmt(inpputString.replace('T', ' ')); 

System.Debug('resultDateTime>> '+resultDateTime);
```

Output:

```
10:10:41:011 USER_DEBUG [4]|DEBUG|resultDateTime>> 2017-02-05 01:44:00
```

Comment: Thank you! The valueOfGmt with the replace got the correctly formatted date time